# Discord OAUTH error: 'unsupported_grant_type',

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, discord

I am trying to implement a Discord-Login onto my Website. Unfortunately I am getting an error from discord.

Does anybody see, whats wrong with my code?

FYI: I am already get back the code from discord. So my first request is working fine.

What I want to do with the Data:

I want to get the user_ID so I can add groups to the user on my Discord Server.

ERROR:

```
error: 'unsupported_grant_type',
error_description: 'Grant type None is not supported'
```

Code:

```
router.get('/account-settings/connections/discord/callback', (async (req, res) => {

  const code = await req.query.code;
  const creds = btoa(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`);

  fetch(`https://discordapp.com/api/oauth2/token`, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
              Authorization: `Basic ${creds}`,
          },
          body: querystring.stringify({
              grant_type: 'authorization_code',
              code: code,
              redirect_uri: dis_redirect
          }),
      })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((body) => console.log(body));
})
```

Thank you very much in advance!!!

The best regards,
Joshy

Comment: You might be missing: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I'm not certain! Also `await req.query.code` is suspect. Does it cointain what you think it does?

Comment: Where I have to place it in? The req.query.code contains the code I am getting from the discord oauth when the user authorized his profile to my app. So yes that should be correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay for everybody else, who has this problem. I was able to fix this with parsing all information in the body and setting up the content type in the headers. Here is a working code:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('client_id', CLIENT_ID);
  params.append('client_secret', CLIENT_SECRET);
  params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
  params.append('code', code);
  params.append('redirect_uri', dis_redirect);

  fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
    method: 'post',
    body: params,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
  }).then(r => r.json()).then(async Response => {
```

In the code variable, I have stored the request query, I am getting back from TwithOauth (After autorization of the user).
Client ID and Client Secret you will get from your Discord Application. The dis_redirect virable is containing my redirection link, which is just blank string of my Link, I have setup to get the router.

Nothing more is needed.

You will get a JSON responded, which you can work with. If you want to get the users data (like me) this following code is what you searching for:

```
let refresh_token = Response.refresh_token;
    let accessToken = Response.access_token;

    var site = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me", {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`}
    });
    var response = await site.json();
    console.log(response);
  });
```

This code you will place directly in the new opened async function. There you have it. All users data, you will need.

I hope I was able to help someone. If you have any questions, just let me know!

The best regards,
Joshy